# Create a new object every 5 elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm going through each div with a class name and throwing the html into a key/value object. My issue is that to go further than what I have now, one big object will not cut it. I need to either put every 5 into a different object, or do something similar to .slice() to break it down afterwards. I'm lost because, as much as this would be easy to do if I knew how many upfront, I'd like to make this as dynamic as possible. A user may have 27 .example div's vs the 3 I have below. It's in an object now and not an array as the key/value object plays nicer with dojo charting, and a few other things I'm trying to do. As an over simplified example:

```
    //HTML
    <div class="example">
        <div class="title"></div>
        <div class="definition"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="example">
        <div class="title"></div>
        <div class="definition"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="example">
        <div class="title"></div>
        <div class="definition"></div>
    </div>

    //JS
    var titles = {};
    $('.example').each(function(index) {    
        var exampleTitle = $(this).find('.title').html();
        var exampleDef = $(this).find('.definition').html();
        titles[exampleTitle] = exampleDef;
    });
```

In my mind, instead of titles = {}, I'd like to push every 5 into a seperate object.

```
    //...
    titles2= {}; 
    titles3={};
    etc
```

without hard coding the amount in the code beforehand.

(i.e. I don't want to say if(index>5) and specify titles2 in the code, the user may have many more than that, and hard-coding multiples of 5 up to whatever arbitrary number I can think of supporting doesn't seem very efficient.)

Or a way to use multiples of 5 similar to .slice().

```
titles.slice(0,5); //obviously does not work on objects, just as an example
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2):

```
$('.example').each(function(index) {    
    var exampleTitle = $(this).find('.title').html();
    var exampleDef = $(this).find('.definition').html();
    var titles;
    if (! window['titles' + (index / 5)]) {
         titles = window['titles' + (index / 5)] = {};
    }
    titles[exampleTitle] = exampleDef;
});
```

Now you will get objects like titles0, titles1, ... in the `window` scope.